Why python runs the unused task1
In this python code that is mostly sample code for tasks and routins:
import asyncio

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(1, 'hello'))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(2, 'world'))

    await task2

asyncio.run(main())

I expect:
world

but I get:
hello
world

What am I doing wrong?

asyncio.create_task -
"Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and schedule its execution. Return the Task object." Working as intended.

@matszwecja Thanks, but why when I replace "await task2" with "await task1" I only get "hello" in the output? Or when I remove "await task2" I do not get anything in the output?

Because your loop closes before other tasks get to finish. If you don't await at all, your loop closes immediately, so no output at all. If you await task1, your loop closes after 1s, so task2 doesn't have time to finish. When you await task2, task1 has enough time to run fully, even though it is not awaited.

Await just stops your program and actually waits until the asynchronous task is finished.
The chronology looks like this:

Run main
First task gets a delay of 1s and will output 'hello'
Second tasks gets a delay of 2s and will output 'world'
We wait for the second task to finish
Program ends with output from both tasks

Now if we switch await task2 to await task1 it will look like this:

Run main
First task gets a delay of 1s and will output 'hello'
Second tasks gets a delay of 2s and will output 'world'
We wait for the first task to finish. Except this time first task will be finished before the second one.
Program ends with output of only 'hello'


Thanks for the comprehensive detailed answer. I'm new to python. It looks kind of ridiculous how these things work in Python comparison to C or java

Is there any equivalent to AWAIT that is non-blocking and lets the calling code run in parallel with the task?

Asyncio has a method called 'gather'. So again, you just await for it the be finished like this: await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)
Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather

@AKTanara In this case you could simply await both.
